# ValidationMessage and ModelState.AddModelError not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I want to do cusotm validation and  return false and show message in case of validation fail.

In controller below code is used to submit posted data to database.

```
       [HttpPost]
       public JsonResult SubmitDa(IList<AdViewModel> s, String section)
           {

            ...........
              ..........


            ModelState.AddModelError("MessageError", "Please enter AttendanceDate");

             JSONSubmit r = new JSONSubmit();
            r.ErrorCount = iError;
            r.errors = errors;

           return Json(r, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       }
```

Below is the code in view file (cshtml)

```
       @Html.ValidationMessage("MessageError")  
        .....  

       $.AJAX call to `SubmitDa` controller's method.
```

Message is not appearing at "MessageError" validation message. please suggest me what is wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's because you're returned a jsonified version of your r variable. The ModelState normally gets added to your response object, but since you are now only returning the json, it is not send back to the page.

Comment: Plz suggest, how i could handle validation in this situation ? basically, AJAX call is made to submit data to server but there are couple of validation and if it trues then only have to accomplish post data else show error messages. How to achieve here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the modelstate for errors you shouldn't really be sending a JSON response. Having said that you can handle it by having the controller return JSON only in the case of success, and the page handles the response differently

IE:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitDa(IList<AdViewModel> s, String section)
{

        ...........
          ..........


        ModelState.AddModelError("MessageError", "Please enter AttendanceDate");

         JSONSubmit r = new JSONSubmit();
        r.ErrorCount = iError;
        r.errors = errors;
       if (r.ErrorCount != 0)
           return Json(r, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       return View("ViewName", s); // <-- just return the model again to the view,
                                   //     complete with modelstate!
}
```

on the page something like:

```
<script>

$("#buttonId").click({
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "PostBackURL",
     data: $("#formID").serialize(),
     success: function (response){
       //test for a property in the JSON response
       if(response.ErrorCount && response.ErrorCount == 0) 
       {
           //success! do whatever else you want with the response

       } else {
          //fail - replace the HTML with the returned response HTML.
          var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
          newDoc.write(response);
          newDoc.close();
       }

     }
   });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Should it work if return `View("ViewName", s);` // s does not contain the property which will be display as an error message? Can we show the error message which is written here - `ModelState.AddModelError("MessageError", "Please enter AttendanceDate");` in controller. View should display error at - ` @Html.ValidationMessage("MessageError")`.?

Comment: Add a validationSummary (`@Html.ValidationSummary` )- and the error will be displayed there.

Comment: Tried both of these individually -  @*@Html.ValidationMessage("AttendanceDateMessage")                              @Html.ValidationSummary(true)*@ . Passed ModelState.AddModelError("MessageError", "Please enter AttendanceDate");

 or ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Please enter AttendanceDate"); but it did not work.

Comment: hm - should have worked - assuming you were replacing the page HTML as shown. Did you examine the HTTP response using firebug/chrome/ie dev tools and check if the response was being returned with the error in it's html?